# use two variables and an expression within a plotmath()

Tags: r, plotmath

I would like to do something like this:

```
Title<-paste(typis[which.panel],bquote(nu[x]==.(typas[which.panel])),sep="")
```

where typas is a vector of numbers and typis a vector of chars e.g.:

```
typas<-1:3
typis<-letters[1:3]
```

`which.panel` is an integer in 1:3 (this is because `Title` will change 
according to the panel)

and `nu[x]` should show as a `plotmath` object.
but R ignores everything after the comma in the 
`paste` :(

Comment: So what is `which.panel`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want the panel label (`typis`) followed by the `nu[x]` bit in a single expression?

Comment: almost; I want typis[1] followed by nu[x] followed by typas[1]. The first and third should be evaluated, the second not. So the string will be:// "a " $\nu_x=$ 1 // where $\nu_x$ should show a plotmat symbol...is this clear!?

Comment: @user189035 Check out my Answer, is that what you wanted/meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't immediately clear what you want, but if it is just an expression containing both bits of information, you don't need `paste()`, just include both bits in the `bquote()` call and separate them with one or more `~` depending on how much space you want. The key thing to note is that `bquote()` can take as many different `.()` as you want to include.

```
typas <- 1:3
typis <- letters[1:3]
which.panel <- 2
expr <- bquote(.(typis[which.panel]) ~~ nu[x]==.(typas[which.panel]))

plot(1:10, main = expr)
```

If you need a bit more formatting around the `typis` part of the expression (say to add a `:` if this is a panel label), then add this inside the relevant `.()`:

```
expr2 <-
  bquote(.(paste0(typis[which.panel], ":")) ~~ nu[x]==.(typas[which.panel]))
plot(1:10, main = expr2)
```

Of course, that could be done outside the expression:

```
typis2 <- paste0(letters[1:3], ":")
expr3 <- bquote(.(typis2[which.panel]) ~~ nu[x]==.(typas[which.panel]))
plot(1:10, main = expr3)
```

The three plots look like this:

[image]

The last two are essentially equivalent.

Comment: thanks that's *exactly* what i wanted to know...didn't know of the ~!